# почему не работает код и как вывести отсортированный массив?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int* ar; // ** Указатель на int
int swaps = 0, compares = 0;
void funcprint(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
void quickSort(int a[], long N) {
    cout << "N=" << N << "  ";
    if (N < 2) {
        cout << '\n';
        return;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        cout << a[k] << " ";
    cout << ";   ";


    long i = 0, j = N - 1;
    int p = a[N >> 1];

    while (i < j) {
        while (a[i] < p) { compares++;  i++; }
        while (a[j] > p) { compares++;  j--; }
        if (i < j) {
            swaps++;
            swap(a[i++], a[j--]);
        }
    }
    cout << "p=" << p
        << " j=" << j
        << " i=" << i << "   1: ";
    for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
        cout << a[k] << " ";
    cout << ";   2: ";
    for (int k = i; k < N; k++)
        cout << a[k] << " ";
    cout << ";   ";

    funcprint(ar, 9); // Выводить массив с первого элемента в текущем узле рекурсии
    quickSort(a, j);
    quickSort(a + i, N - i);
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = { 5,2,1,9,1,4,6,2,10 };
    ar = a; // ** Установить указатель на первый элемент массива
    int N = 9;
    quickSort(a, N);
    funcprint(a, N);
    cout << "compares=" << compares << endl;
    cout << "swaps=" << swaps << endl;
}
```

Comment: опишите как не работает.

Comment: Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted

Comment: возможно индекс переменной вышел за пределы.

Comment: Не подскажете ли еще как вывести отсортированный массив?

Comment: вначале его отсортировать, а потом `for (int x : a) { std::cout << x << " "; } std::cout << "\n";}`

Comment: используйте std::cout

Comment: может знаете почему сортировка не работает?

Comment: Для начала -- у вас в массиве 9 чисел, а N = 10 (передаваемый в функцию размер массива)

Comment: у вас `j = N` и вызов `while (a[j] > p)` вызывает исключение. Так как в массиве индексы от **0** .. **N-1**

Comment: почему не выводит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В соответствии с [algorithm quicksort Хоара](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) из википедии, который, похоже, вы пытаетесь реализовать, функция, написанная на С++ с тем же прототипом, что и ваша, может выглядеть вот так:

```
void quickSort (int a[], long N) {
  if (N < 2)
    return;
  
  long i = 0, j = N - 1;
  int p = a[N >> 1];
    
  while (i < j) {
    while (a[i] < p) i++;
    while (a[j] > p) j--;
    
    if (i < j)
      swap(a[i++], a[j--]);
  }
  
  quickSort(a, j);
  quickSort(a + i, N - i);
}
```

Обратите внимание на `if (N < 2) return;` в ее начале. Это позволяет избежать  проверок перед рекурсивными вызовами, которые вы делаете в своем коде.

Замечу также, что перестановка элементов в соответствии с текстом алгоритма из википедии должна записываться именно так: ***`if (i < j) swap(a[i++], a[j--]);`***

а не как у вас:

```
   if (i <= j)
        swap(a[i], a[j]);
```

---

**Update for debugging print**

```
int* ar; // ** Указатель на int

void quickSort(int a[], long N) {
  cout << "N=" << N << "  ";
  if (N < 2) {
    cout << '\n';
    return;
  }
  for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
      cout << a[k] << " ";
  cout << ";   ";
  
  
    long i = 0, j = N - 1;
    int p = a[N >> 1];

    while (i < j) {
        while (a[i] < p) i++;
        while (a[j] > p) j--;

        if (i < j)
            swap(a[i++], a[j--]);
    }
    cout << "p=" << p
     << " j=" << j
     << " i=" << i << "   1: ";
    for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
      cout << a[k] << " ";
    cout << ";   2: ";
    for (int k = i; k < N; k++)
      cout << a[k] << " ";
    cout << ";   ";
    
    funcprint(ar, 9); // Выводить массив с первого элемента в текущем узле рекурсии
    quickSort(a, j);
    quickSort(a + i, N - i);
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = { 5,2,1,9,1,4,6,2,10 };
    ar = a; // ** Установить указатель на первый элемент массива
    int N = 9;
    quickSort(a, N);
    funcprint(a, N);
}
```

Я исправил N из вашего кода на 9 (может и еще какие-то мелкие правки внес)

Результат запуска

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ g++ ttt.cpp -g
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
N=9  5 2 1 9 1 4 6 2 10 ;   p=1 j=1 i=2   1: 1 1 ;   2: 2 9 5 4 6 2 10 ;   1 1 2 9 5 4 6 2 10 
N=1  
N=7  2 9 5 4 6 2 10 ;   p=4 j=2 i=3   1: 2 2 4 ;   2: 5 6 9 10 ;   1 1 2 2 4 5 6 9 10 
N=2  2 2 ;   p=2 j=0 i=1   1: 2 ;   2: 2 ;   1 1 2 2 4 5 6 9 10 
N=0  
N=1  
N=4  5 6 9 10 ;   p=9 j=2 i=2   1: 5 6 9 ;   2: 9 10 ;   1 1 2 2 4 5 6 9 10 
N=2  5 6 ;   p=6 j=1 i=1   1: 5 6 ;   2: 6 ;   1 1 2 2 4 5 6 9 10 
N=1  
N=1  
N=2  9 10 ;   p=10 j=1 i=1   1: 9 10 ;   2: 10 ;   1 1 2 2 4 5 6 9 10 
N=1  
N=1  
1 1 2 2 4 5 6 9 10 
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Кстати, интересно что уже после третьего вызова массив оказывается отсортированным, но алгоритму требуется сделать еще 10 вызовов, чтобы установить этот факт.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120203/discussion-on-answer-by-avp--------).